# jQuery listen for change in span number

Tags: jquery, bind, html

I have a number within a span element that changes often. I want to be able to detect any changes in this number and store that number in a variable.

so far I have tried this:

```
var x = $('#mynum').text();
```

This code however doesn't detect any changes - it only gets the value when the page first loads.

I have also tried this:

```
$('#mynum').bind('change',function(){

alert('wahoo!');   });
```

However I cannot get it to even make the alert.

What would be the best way to detect the changes and store the number in a variable whenever it does change?

Comment: What's making the content of the `<span>` change in the first place?

Comment: Why not have whatever is changing the value also store off that value in a variable?

Comment: thanks, I couldn't really figure it out because it was using JSON data, but after a while i found a way to store it into a variable...the answer provided by alienwebguy is pretty much just as good..would there be a benefit of one method over another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change event only happens from the browser on the blurring of form fields. If you're changing the value of a span from your script, you need to `$('#mynum').trigger('change');`. Then your bind will work, assuming the element `#mynum` was in the DOM when the bind was set. If not, bind to a consistent parent element and delegate it with `on`:

```
$('#myParentNode').on('change','#mynum', function() {
    alert('wahooo!');
});
```

Comment: OP stated that the number was "within a span element", not a text field.

Comment: The `change` event won't be fired here if the content of the `<span>` changes... it only applies to `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Dude, that's why I said trigger the change event. Read my answer.