# Re-run javascript code when the value changes

Tags: javascript

I have two files: a html file (with the code below) and a javascript file (it creates a value for the `<span id="quantity">`) The code works fine, but the word only changes if I refresh the whole page.

I want the word to change from 'articles' to 'article' or vice versa as soon as the 'quantity' changes. Is this possible? And if so, how?

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity"></span>
<span id="quantityText"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(window).load(function() 
        {
        var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity"),
            quantityText = document.getElementById("quantityText");
        if (parseInt(quantity.innerHTML, 10) === 1) {
            quantityText.innerHTML = "article";
       } else {
            quantityText.innerHTML = "articles";
        }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: How are the contents of `quantity` being changed? Find the JS that is updating the contents of that span and add a trigger there to run the code that is currently in your window load function.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into MVVC framework like [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/). For example, you would set the contents of the *#quantity* `<span></span>` element to be an observable.

However, try reading [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536137/jquery-listen-for-change-in-span-number) to find a solution similar to what you probably are hoping for. In summary, change events only occur from the browser on the blurring of form fields, so you'll need to implement a `$("#quantity").trigger('change')`

Once you have a trigger set-up after the DOM element has been loaded, you can do the following:

```
$('#myParentNode').on('change','#mynum', function() {
    // Add your logic in here
    $('#quantityText').text('articles')  .... .. .. ..... 
});
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend using knockout for this

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the `span` element doesn't fire a `change` event, so you cannot subscribe to it, like you would normally do in an `input` element.

However, you can trigger such an event using jQuery in the same code, which changes the value  of the span (I assume there is such code, because normally `span`s don't change value).

Here is an example which simulates this change every 10 seconds, and triggers the `change` event. It also includes a handler for that change event, which duplicates the value in the other span.

```
<span id="quantity" class="simpleCart_quantity">1</span>
<span id="quantityText"></span>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var quantity = $("#quantity"),
        quantityText = $("#quantityText");

    setInterval(function() {
        var currentVal = parseInt(quantity.html());
        if (currentVal >= 10) {
            quantity.html(1);
        }
        else {
            quantity.html(currentVal + 1);
        }
        quantity.trigger('change');
    }, 10000);

    quantity.on('change', function(sender, args) {
        quantityText.html($(this).html());
    });
});

</script>
```